# Combo box autocomplete blanks when enter key pressed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, combobox, autocomplete

I am working with C# in visual studio 2013 (winforms). I have a combo box which contains a long list of shop names. The combobox has the autocomplete property set to 'suggestappend' as per the msdn article: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autocompletemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The program displays the name of the shop on the _selectionchangecommitted event.

When selecting an item in the combobox list, the user can start typing the first few letters of the name and the combobox narrows the selection accordingly. It also shows another drop down menu of items that may match the user's selection. (suggest feature of autocomplete)

The combobox will also fill in the text box with the most likely item to match the user's typed letters (append feature of autocomplete)
If this item matches the one the user is looking for, they press 'enter' to select it. Instead of selecting it, the text field reverts to blank.

Also, if the user uses the arrow keys to move down the suggested list then presses 'enter' (the logical thing to do to confirm a suggested selection), the text inside the combo box reverts to blank rather than the selected item.

Has anyone else seen this behaviour in comboboxes? And any idea how to make the enter key select the item properly?

Thanks in advance,
Anya.